# Regex for validation numbers with commas and space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not sure why this regex expression is not working. 
I want to validate if the input is in this format :

1. 12345678,12345678,12345678
2. *space*12345678 , 12345678 , 12345678 , 12345678
3. 12345678,12345678, *space*

It must be 8 digit if not return false. 
Below is the regex expression that i did, But it is working for 2 sets of numbers but when i input another set of numbers validation is not working.

1. Working: 12345678 , 12345678
2. Not Working: 12345678 , 12345678 ,12345678

```
var validate_numbers = /^\s*\d{8}\s*\+*(,\s*\d{8},*)?$/;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to describe what you want to match in more detail. I'm going to assume you want to match 8-digit nums delimited by commas and pluses, possibly followed by commas.

The problem is you're taking at most 2 sets of digits. [Visualization](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%5Cs%2A%5Cd%7B8%7D%5Cs%2A%5C%2B%2A%28%2C%5Cs%2A%5Cd%7B8%7D%2C%2A%29%3F%24&str=12345678%2C12345678%2C+).

Given the assumption above, this is the regex you want:

```
^(\s*\d{8}\s*[+,]?\s*)*$
```

Again, you can visualize it on [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28%5Cs%2a%5Cd%7B8%7D%5Cs%2a%5B%2b,%5D?%5Cs%2a%29%2a%24&str=12345678,12345678,%20).

Comment: Wow, debuggex is brilliant. Thanks for the link! Might i also be so bold as to suggest http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ also.

Comment: Hi, Currently this regex: ^(\s*\d{8}\s*[+,]?\s*)*$ verify for all the situation above. But it return true when my string is 1234567812345678. I've try to edit it. But the result is still the same. Any idea how can i do it? So that the codes can verify the situation above and 1234567812345678?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a little bit more detail about the requirement? Do you need to have a space before comma?

```
\\d{8}(?:,\\d{8})*+
```

Try with it. it works fine with requirement that validates a list of numbers, which have 8 digits, and separated by comma.

Hope it will helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '$' from your current regular expression. It is strictly matching for the end of the line, which is causing your expression to return false on your desired strings. The following code returns TRUE for the strings that you mentioned which were previously returning FALSE.

omgerd I automatically wrote first response in PHP, here is quick JS edit

```
var pattern = /^\s*\d{8}\s*\+*(,\s*\d{8},*)?/;
var data2 = '12345678 , 12345678 ,12345678';
if (pattern.test(data2) != 0) {
    alert("ok");
}
```

Output:
ok

Comment: If you remove $ it will match invalid strings, such as 8 digits followed by only letters.